# Get the value of an authentication token from an Authorization HTTP header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, http-headers

I want to allow access to a resource only when the authorization token contained in the HTTP headers matches token stored in the users table.
i'm using curl as shown below to access the resource:

`$ curl http://localhost:3000/api/v1/tasks.json -H 'Authorization: Token token="S8S4MPqFNdDz3G1jLsC9"'`

in the `tasks#index` method i would like to check whether the token above matches the current user's authentication token stored in the database.
How can i get the token value as an instance variable so that i can use it as shown below:

```
def index
  @token = ???
  if User.exists?(:authentication_token => @token)
    ### code to access the resource
  else
    authenticate_user!
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [railscast,](http://railscasts.com/episodes/352-securing-an-api) I have found the best solution is to use rails [`authenticate_or_request_with_http_token`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Token/ControllerMethods/authenticate_or_request_with_http_token) method like this:

```
class Api::V1::TasksController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :restrict_access 
   respond_to :json

  def index
    @user = User.where("users.authentication_token IS NOT NULL").first
    @tasks = @user.tasks
  end

 private

  def restrict_access
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
    User.exists?(authentication_token: token)
  end
end
```